# C# Param as interface, how to use?

Tags: c#, interface, implementation, implements

I have a class, which implements this simple interface:

```
public interface IPosition
{
    int? Position { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a class to resort collection of classes by this `Position` property:

```
public static class ReorderPositions
{
    public static IList<IPosition> Reorder(IList<IPosition> list)
    {
        // different actions, resorting
        return positionList;
    }
}
```

So, for testing it I create fake class (other properties are not necessary for me of real class for reordering):

```
public class ReorderPositionsFakeModel : IPosition
{
    public int? Position { get; set; }
}
```

Then I created a factory class to fill `List<ReorderPositionsFakeModel>`:

```
    public static class ReorderPositionFakeModelFactory
    {
        public static IList<ReorderPositionsFakeModel> Create(List<int> positions)
        {
            positions = positions.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
            List<ReorderPositionsFakeModel> model = new();
            foreach (var position in positions)
            {
                model.Add(new ReorderPositionsFakeModel { Position = position });
            }
            return model;
        }
    }
```

but when I try to use:

```
var model = ReorderPositionFakeModelFactory.Create(new List<int> { -2, -1, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 18, 19, 20, 21, 23, 24, 25, 26 });
var result = ReorderPositions.Reorder(model);
```

I got:

> Error CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from
> `'System.Collections.Generic.IList<ReorderPositionsFakeModel>'` to
> `'System.Collections.Generic.IList<IPosition>'`

why so? What is wrong? `ReorderPositionsFakeModel` implements `IPosition`, why can't be converted?...

Answer (score 3):

The issue you're facing is due to the fact that you're trying to pass a list of ReorderPositionsFakeModel objects to the ReorderPositions. Reorder method that expects a list of IPosition objects.
Try this:

```
var model = ReorderPositionFakeModelFactory.Create(new List<int> { -2, -1, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 18, 19, 20, 21, 23, 24, 25, 26 });
var result = ReorderPositions.Reorder(model.Cast<IPosition>().ToList());
```

Answer (score 1):

`IList<ReorderPositionsFakeModel>` is not `IList<IPosition>` (for example you can add `IPosition` to the latter, but not to the former). There are several ways to handle this. One is to use [covariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/variance-in-generic-interfaces) `IEnumerable<out T>` interface instead of `IList`:

```cs
public static class ReorderPositions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IPosition> Reorder(IEnumerable<IPosition> list)
    {
        // different actions, resorting
        return default;
    }
}

public static class ReorderPositionFakeModelFactory
{
    public static IEnumerable<ReorderPositionsFakeModel> Create(List<int> positions)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Or create new list with the required type:

```cs
ReorderPositions.Reorder(model.ToList<IPosition>());
```